# Magento 2 Catch customer creation event on both frontend and admin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, event-observer, customer, customer-account

I'm aware of the event emitted from CreatePost.php

```
$this->_eventManager->dispatch(
    'customer_register_success',
    ['account_controller' => $this, 'customer' => $customer]
);
```

but this is only for frontend new customer event, I have to find the best area to enter some code that runs only once when a new customer is created.

Edit: customer can be created thru frontend, API, admin page. And I need to catch all.

Edit 2: I'm trying to find the last event when a customer is created or edited, I have to run a reindex command after.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Saveafter observer is good for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frontend, Admin, API, we should use Plugin for : `\Magento\Customer\Model\AccountManagement::createAccount()`

Comment: Wouldn't that get me the "before" call, where the model hasn't been created yet?

Comment: Actually I don’t know your purpose. I just gave you a suggestion. Can you update your question more details?

Comment: One of the 3rd party extensions that I have, has some custom attributes on customer model, and it's forcing me to run a reindex on new customers, and everytime a customer group is changed, I've already tried update on save also, I still need to reindex customer grid every time.